# extending default options in an extended class the correct way

Tags: javascript, class

I am trying to implement plugins from a base class, and I want to be able to extend default options on every level (base class, plugin or component implementation)

I have the a JavaScript class as a base for all my plugins

```
 export default class PluginBase {
  /**
   * @param {object} defaults
   * @param {object} options
   */
  constructor(defaults, options) {
    // extend default options
    this.options = jQuery.extend(true, {}, defaults, options)
  }
}
```

then let's say I implement a carousel plugin that extends this class

```
import PluginBase from 'project/plugin-base'

//default options at a 'carousel level'
const DEFAULTS = {
  some_default : "options"
}

export default class CarouselPlugin extends PluginBase {
  /**
   * @param {object} defaults
   * @param {object} options
   */
  constructor(defaults, options) {
    super(DEFAULTS, options)

    // extend default options
    this.options = $.extend(true, {}, DEFAULTS, options)
  }

  init() {
      // Initialization
  }


  someCarouselMethod() {
    // SomePluginMethod
  }

}
```

at this point it works fine , I am having trouble in the next step, I want to extend that Carousel class when I use it in a component (because not all carousel would behave the same) and be able to extend default once again, also I would like to be able to put a reference to a method in the component's default.

for the component plugin I have the following class:

```
import CarouselPlugin from 'project/plugins/plugin-carousel'

(function ($) {

  const pluginNAME = `componentSlider`

  class Plugin extends CarouselPlugin {

    constructor(options) {
      super(DEFAUTS, options)

      //extend options
      this.options = $.extend(true, {}, this.defaults, this.options)

      //call init from previous class (that would use the extended options)
      this.init()

      }

    onDragged (event) {
      // onDragged method
    }
  }


  //here goes some logic to attach my plugin to $.fn
}(jQuery))
```

so, if I call my plugin like so : `componentSlider({ //optionshere })` the options of my plugin extend the default and options set in carousel, which extend the default of `PluginBase`.

then I would like to set `DEFAULTS` options on the last class `Plugin`.
I would like to be able to have options like `{ ondrag: this.ondrag()}` which would hold reference to the ondrag method of the `Plugin` class (or to a method named `ondrag` in any parent classes if it exists. I am not sure where to declare the variable `DEFAULTS` as it can not be instantiated before `super()` if it holds reference to `this`.

Comment: A function should not take `defaults` as an argument, it should have them internally.

Comment: good point, makes sense, but then if i do a `this.defaults` in my `Plugin` class, the defaults that are set in `CarouselPlugin` would get overwritten, when I would like to extend them

Comment: It should probably be a static property, or static get method, which creates a default object extending the one of the parent class.